# Why does my function return kotlin.Unit and not a boolean?

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I have created a register screen and am using the ROOM database to store the users. I am successfully adding them to the database. I am trying to run some validation on the entries as I do not want users to have the same username or email. Here is my code for adding them to the database and how I am validating it.

---

this is the function that sends the firstName, lastName, userName, password, address, city, postalCode, email, phone to the database.

the `mCustomerViewModel.addCustomer(customer)`, returns a Boolean:

1. if it's true User Added
2. if its false, duplicate user

   ```
   val customer = Customer(0, firstName, lastName, userName, password,address,city,postalCode,email,phone)
   val flag = mCustomerViewModel.addCustomer(customer)
   println("FLAG ---> "+flag)

   if(flag.equals(true)){
       Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
   }else{
       Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
   }
   ```

---

here is the `CustomerViewModel` class:

```
fun addCustomer(customer: Customer){
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
        repository.addCustomer(customer) // call to CustomerRepository 
    }
```

and then from `CustomerViewModel` class, we call `CustomerRepository`

```
fun addCustomer(customer: Customer): Boolean {
    try {
        customerDao.addCustomers(customer)
        return true
    }catch (ex: Exception){
        return false
    }
}
```

---

As you can see, in my function where the customer is being added, I have a print statement `println("FLAG ---> "+flag)` to check and see what the function was returning. I got this in the console:

[image]

When I run the app, the if statement doesn't run, only the else block does, because "flag" actually does not equal "true".

How can i fix this?

Comment: Since your repository `addCustomer` function is not a suspend function (which it should have been), you can simply remove the `viewModelScope.launch` call and directly return the repo result back to the caller from the view model.

Comment: I originally did have the "suspend", but android studio didn't like it there and asked me to `remove redundant suspend`.

Comment: That warning was because your Dao function isn't probably marked with `suspend`.

Comment: i have updated the question with the changes recommended, but now i am getting a new error

Comment: What room version are you using?

Comment: I originally had it at 2.3.0, but was getting the following error `Suspend function 'addCustomer' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function` but then i read online i should lower my version to 2.5.0, because its more stable.

Comment: im sorry. I can revert the changes if you'd like

Comment: @Tenfour04 hey, i have changed it back to the original question. My apologies again.

Comment: @navsharma That's OK, thanks. I know you're new here so you're not used to the conventions. Generally, all the rules and guidelines about questions here, and the voting system, have to do with the goal of making them as useful as possible for future readers, not just useful to the person asking the question. Feel free to open a new question about your new issue if it hasn't been asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `addCustomer` function launches a coroutine and doesn't return anything (except the implicit Unit). Notice you did not define any return type. It is not possible for a non-suspend function to return the result of a launched coroutine because it returns before the coroutine necessarily has been run yet. You should either turn it into a suspend function that directly calls `repository.addCustomer(customer)` without launching another coroutine, or you can give it a callback parameter to call at the end of the launched coroutine.

Third option is to change `viewModelScope.launch` to `return viewModelScope.async` and make the function return type `Deferred<Boolean>`. Then when you need the result, you can call `await()` on the Deferred in a coroutine.

Comment: i have updated the question with the changes recommended, but now i am getting a new error